# Upvotes and post-community wiki question deletion

Tags: support, bug, reputation, community-wiki

Recently an answer of mine was subsumed by community wiki. A point was awarded during wikification that I think was not tallied. Then when my answer was de-wikified and I was able to delete the question I *may* have been left with a lower score than I had before posting the answer. In other words, it took away the phantom point.

This may be a general problem or I wouldn't ask. While I am looking forward to 2000 and learning the names of future Kentucky Derby winners, I don't pay close attention to the points. So I am not 100% sure this actually happened.

My question is whether it could have happened, and what in general might be done to avoid/correct the situation. Thanks.